# Unable to create and activate Python Virtual Environment using Jenkins Execute Shell

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, virtualenv

I am trying to create a python virtual environment for Django in ubuntu 20.04 using jenkins execute shell. I have seen a solution here at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756728/cannot-activate-python-virtual-env-in-jenkins-shell-script) and trying to reproduce this solution but getting the following error in console output:

> Running as SYSTEM Building in workspace
> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/python_virtual_Env [python_virtual_Env] $
> /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins8922469990510149005.sh ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'virtualenv.seed.embed.via_app_data'
> /tmp/jenkins8922469990510149005.sh: line 3: cd: virtual_django1/bin:
> No such file or directory
> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/python_virtual_Env
> /tmp/jenkins8922469990510149005.sh: line 6: activate: No such file or
> directory Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure Finished:
> FAILURE

Below are my commands which i have used in jenkins execute shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
virtualenv virtual_django1
cd virtual_django1/bin
pwd
dir
source activate
```

I have ran the above commands with and without **#!/bin/bash** but still error persist. How can i get rid off this error in console and get able to create as well activate python virtual environment using jenkins execute shell.

Comment: Adjusted your question's tags a bit: removed `bash`, added `virtualenv` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this issue by creating a virtual envirnoment with another command rather than `virtualenv`. Below is the exact shell commands which will be needed to create and activate the virtual envirnoment for python using jenkins shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt install python3.8-venv
python3 -m venv Virtual_Django
cd my_env/bin
pwd
dir
source activate
```